# WebRTC over the peersm network : 'blob:d6ff3420-cfd5-4f2a-966a-568fb0c6c381'

Tags: local-storage, webrtc

I'm wondering if a WebRTC program can run from a platform like http://peersm.com/peersm (in its own private space or private origin domain)...  This would mean that one could simply upload, host, and use a p2p program using only there browser.

For example, if a WebRTC program were packaged into a single `html` file and provided to the peersm network, a file hash could be obtained and shared.  Another user may then open that file hash and see the `html` file rendered as html under a url that looks like this: `blob:d6ff3420-cfd5-4f2a-966a-568fb0c6c381`...  This works now for simple html.

What I'm not sure about is:  Would WebRTC and local storage then make use of that URL as its own origin?  So, would multiple users be able to find each other (webrtc), would they be able to then save data in local storage (html5/localstorage)?  That network and data would then be private from peersm's data.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few services do file sharing with WebRTC and Filesystem api (not local-storage): 
https://www.sharefest.me/ - It does many-to-many p2p as you suggested
https://rtccopy.com/ - More of a 1-to-1 service

But the anonymity layer in peersm is exactly what prevents it to be a real browser-to-browser network with no servers.

Comment: Thank you for the links.  RTCCopy looks very slick and has a simple messaging feature.  It may be a great way to test this.

Comment: WebRTC requires a server to connect browsers together.  The anonymity layer is on-top of this layer.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by anonymity. But 2 WebRTC connected browsers know about each other's ip's

Answer (score 1):

"But the anonymity layer in peersm is exactly what prevents it to be a real browser-to-browser network with no servers."

Clarification needed here, please take a look at the target phase for Peersm http://www.peersm.com and https://github.com/Ayms/node-Tor for the specs.

The target phase with WebRTC is totally serverless, so browser to browser and does even allow to stream/download anonymously from other P2P networks such as bittorrent (via the Peersm clients which are headless browsers running in background)

Comment: You don't necessarly need servers for WebRTC, you can use the peers to discover the others, you just need to know about one first. And indeed two webRTC connected browsers know about their IP address, that's why Peersm is using several hops between peers via the Tor protocol so they don't know whom is connected to whom, whom is requesting what and whom is sending what.